# How does one programmatically create and assign a static TwiML Bin as an SMS response?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically (in C#) create and assigned a TwiML Sms response to incoming sms messages to a phone number.   I know how to do this manually by editing the phone number, and I've seen a lot of examples explaining how to do this with a callback url to one's own website.  But I just want to be able to assign a TwiML Bin sms response without having to manually configure it and without having to use a callback to emit the message each time.  The message will never change so it doesn't make sense to use a callback or a more powerful programmatic feature.

I just want to be able to assign an TwiML bin to a phone number as a sms response programmatically in a similar fashion to how would with the UI.   I saw some examples in PHP that show how to create and update a TwiML bin programmatically and I guessing I can assign TwiML bin url to a phone number SMsUrl property. But there are a lot of small blanks in this process. I haven't yet found an example of this in C# and, while there are a lot of TwilMl docs, the docs are largely silent on programmatic TwilMl bin usage.

**If I just want to set a fixed text twiML bin response to a twilio phone number I create programmatically in C# how would I do that (without having to host an endpoint)?**

If I have to precreate the twiML bin with UI and use its url in a programmatic context as a string, that would be a close second best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TwiML Bin isn't the best solution since it cannot be programmatically created (so it will be your second best solution).

You can programmatically create a Studio Flow, covered in a recent blog/webinar [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/twilio-releases-summer-2020-recap), or using the Twilio Functions API (more involved).

That said, if you do use a TwiML bin, you can phones the IncomingPhoneNumber resource to set your Twilio Phone number to point to the URL (Webhook) of your pre-created TwiML Bin programmatically, details are [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource) (look at the update code example in the upper right side and adjust the relevant parameters).

Comment: Fascinating subject.. thx for the links, I did not know twilio existed,,

Comment: Ok, so I can set the SmsUrl and VoiceUrl properties to TwiML Bin urls and that should set them up to respond to incoming sms messages and voice calls.